# How to capture and forward SNMP messages using WinSNMP?

Tags: sockets, snmp, winsnmp

I'm fairly new to SNMP/WinSNMP and I'm trying to access what it would take to accept SNMP traffic on ports 161/162 and forward it to another device.  I would like to be able to examine messages and possibly modify them before passing them to the device.

Would WinSNMP agent APIs be suitable for it?  Are there any examples out there how to accomplish this in C++?

I'd appreciate any pointers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to make a Proxy Agent. There are already a great number of such implemented, so in order to avoid reinventing the wheel, do a web search for "windows snmp proxy" and see if you could use one of those products instead.